# Automatically round Django's DecimalField according to the max_digits and decimal_places attributes before calling save()

Tags: python, django

I want to automatically round Django's DecimalField according to the max_digits and decimal_places attributes before calling save() function in ModelForm.

currently using the following:

- django 1.8
- python 2.7

What I have tried so far.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10554/

---

**models.py**

```
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 19, decimal_places = 2)
```

**views.py**

P.S. gonna apply it in different fields and in different models

```
data = {"amount" : 100.1234,"name":"John Doe",...}
form = My_form(data)
if form.is_valid(): //the error throws from here.
    form.save()
else:
    raise ValueError(form.errors)
```

**forms.py**

I plan to clean the fields in clean() function and do the rounding off of all decimal fields but when I try to print the raw_data, there's no 'amount field'.

```
class My_form(forms.ModelForm):
    Class Meta:
        model = My_model
        fields = ('amount','name')
    def clean(self):
        raw_data = self.cleaned_data
        print(raw_data) //only prints {'name' : 'John Doe'}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mainly getting the error because `forms.DecimalField` has separate validators from `models.DecimalField`:

```
data = {'amount': 1.12345 }

class NormalForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits = 19, decimal_places = 2)

normal_form = NormalForm(data)
normal_form.is_valid()  # returns False
normal_form.cleaned_data  # returns {}
```

and `forms.DecimalField` is used by default for forms for models with fields of class `models.DecimalField`. You could do something like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal

def round_decimal(value, places):
    if value is not None:
        # see https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize for options
        return value.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -places)
    return value

class RoundingDecimalFormField(forms.DecimalField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(RoundingDecimalFormField, self).to_python(value)
        return round_decimal(value, self.decimal_places)

class RoundingDecimalModelField(models.DecimalField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        # you could actually skip implementing this
        value = super(RoundingDecimalModelField, self).to_python(value)
        return round_decimal(value, self.decimal_places)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = { 'form_class': RoundingDecimalFormField }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(RoundingDecimalModelField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Now anywhere you are using `models.DecimalField`, use `RoundingDecimalModelField` instead. Any form you use with those models will now also use the custom form field.

```
class RoundingForm(forms.Form):
    amount = RoundingDecimalFormField(max_digits = 19, decimal_places = 2)

data = {'amount': 1.12345 }

rounding_form = RoundingForm(data)
rounding_form.is_valid()  # returns True
rounding_form.cleaned_data  # returns {'amount': Decimal('1.12')}
```

Comment: It works now. I just added "RoundingDecimalFormField" in my form fields without changing the "models.DecimalField". It's really a pain that I need to do this in all of my forms though.

Comment: Thanks @Vin-G you did really save my day.

Comment: Right, you don't really need to update the model field's `to_python` if your form field does the quantization for you, as shown here. Using the `formfield` method on a custom model field is a nice improvement over my first take on it. And because validators are run after the form field's `to_python` you don't need to change them. If you use an update model field with `formfield` shown as here, you shouldn't need to update forms unless you're already overriding the field settings.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I suggested a small inversion error ( => kwargs.update(defaults))

Comment: Replying to suggested edit: I'd rather say `super().formfield(**defaults)` instead of swapping `defaults` and `kwargs`, the order matters and I'd expect this to override `form_class`, if one is provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you are assigning directly to a model instance, you don't need to worry about it. The field object will quantize the value (rounding it) to the decimal point level you set in your model definition.

If you are dealing with a `ModelForm`, the default `DecimalField` will require that any input match the model field's decimal points. The easiest way to handle this in general is probably to subclass the model `DecimalField`, removing the decimal-specific validator and relying on the underlying conversion to quantize the data, with something like this:

```
from django.db.models.fields import DecimalField

class RoundingDecimalField(DecimalField):

    @cached_property
    def validators(self):
        return super(DecimalField, self).validators

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'max_digits': self.max_digits,
            'decimal_places': 4, # or whatever number of decimal places you want your form to accept, make it a param if you like
            'form_class': forms.DecimalField,
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(RoundingDecimalField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Then in your models:

```
amount = RoundingDecimalField(max_digits = 19, decimal_places = 2)
```

(Don't actually put the field class in the same field as the model, that's just for example.)

This is probably less correct in absolute terms than defining a custom field form, which was my first suggestion, but is less work to use.

Comment: Is there a global function that automatically roundoff all the decimal fields?

Comment: No, you have to tell it how precisely you want things rounded. What situation are you in where you can't control the input beforehand?

Comment: Ok, after a lot of code diving it looks like at recent versions of Django should do this for you if you've assigned directly to a model instance - what version are you on? Are you saving a model instance, or are you saving a form?

Comment: django 1.8. There are times that I use either one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115265/discussion-between-aldesabido-and-peter-deglopper).

Comment: That's because the actual form field being used (`django.form.fields.DecimalField`) will have separate validators than the model field (`django.db.models.DecimalField`). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/forms/fields/#DecimalField. What you want to do is to use a combination of this updated answer with the old answer (custom model field class with custom form field class)

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper do you have any reference about that automatic rounding being added to Django recently?

Comment: @JozefKnaperek - do you mean when was it added, or how does it work? The former doesn't really fit in a comment's space, but look at the `to_python` method on `DecimalField` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1554 as of this comment) for how it gets turned into a `Decimal` from any convertable value, and then the `get_db_prep_save` method, which calls `adapt_decimalfield_value` from django/django/db/backends/base/operations.py, which in turn calls `format_number` from django/django/db/backends/utils.py before writing to the db.

Comment: As for when - checking github commit logs make it look like that behavior has been around a fairly long time. I didn't mean to say that it's definitely not present in older versions, just that I hadn't checked them.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set widget to limit decimal number input form render just using this code

```
from django import forms

class DecimalNumberInput(forms.NumberInput):
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):

        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        try:
            if self.attrs['decimal_places'] and isinstance(self.attrs['decimal_places'], int) :
                context['widget']['value'] = str(round(float(context['widget']['value']),self.attrs['decimal_places']))
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        return context
class NormalForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits = 19, decimal_places = 2 , widget=DecimalNumberInput(attrs={'decimal_places':2}))
```